# Calling a method or useState setState in an export function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component, this component calls the `setName()` method inside the `useUsers` class. The problem is I get a response from the backend in the `Information` export function. My question is, is there any way to call the `setNewUser` method? This is used in the `useUsers` object array function? And I would like to call this in the `Information` file.

So I have three files

```
- Users (React Component)
- useUsers (object array function)
- Information (export function)
```

I would like to call the method `useUsers` (which can be found in the file `useUsers`) in the file `Information`

```
function User(props) {
    const messagesEndRef = createRef(null);
    const { names, setName} = useUsers(ID);

    // Will be calling when a user input a name inside of the input field
    const sendNamesToTheBackend = async () => {
            setName(Name); 
    };
    return (
                ...
                           {names.map((name, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div>
                                    ... 
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                ...
               {
               // Here is only an input field and a button nothing more 
               // and this button calls at onClick the method sendNamesToTheBackend 
               }
    );
}

export default User;
```

useUsers

```
const useUsers = (userID) => {
    const [names, setName] = useState([])  

    const setName = (name) => {
        // Goes to the backend
    }

    const setNewUser = (name) => {
      
        // This should be called 
        setName((names) => [...name])
    }

    return { names, setName, setNewUser }
}

export default useUsers
```

Information

```
// With this I get a response from the backend
// This is how the whole file looks like, here is only this access from the backend in it more not
// I still call in other this user with import user from './Information'. therefore the export
const user = calling(URL) // Important: The user is also a variable/object, which I call in other classes. Therefore this should not be set again. 
user.get((name) => {
    console.log('The new name is: ', name)
    // now call the the method setNewUser() from the useUsers file
   // So that I can call this setName, or simply so that I can also use this setName here
})
export default user
```

---

What I tried with the help of @Asim-Ali

```
const user = calling(URL)
const { setNewUser } = useUser()
user.get((name) => {
    console.log('The new name is: ', name)
    setNewUser(name)
 }
    
export default user
```

I got the error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
```

Answer (score 0):

just include setNewUser() function in return object in useUser file and import useUser function in information file and destructure your desired seNewUser() function as you done in User component

return { names, setName, setNewUser  }

in information file just destructre setNewUser
const { setNewUser } = useUser()

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I didn't show is that `useUser` still gets a unique ID with it. So the call in `MessageSide` would be `const { names, setName} = useUsers(ID)`. 
And am I then also referencing the same messages? Or another one?

Comment: As soon as I build it in like this `const { setNewUser } = useUser()` inside of the `Information`, I get the following error  `×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:`

Comment: please let me know are useUsers  and information in the User component ?

Comment: Only `useUsers` is in the `User`  component `const { names, setName} = useUsers(ID);`